# Magento 2.3.5-p2 with Stripe Plugin 3.0.0: New order emails being sent twice

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, sales-order, order-email, stripe

Checking out with Stripe plugin for magento (ver 3.0.0) on Magento 2.3.5-p2 sends out 2 "New order confirmation" emails with the same order number, no invoice email gets sent.

Tried checking out with another payment method like "**Purchase order**" and "**Bank Transfer**" and only 1 "New order confirmation" gets sent.

Tried with Stripe Magento Plugin 2.8.4 and only 1 "New order confirmation" email gets sent, so it appears that this is an issue with Stripe Magento Plugin 3.0.0

Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales Email > "Sales" and "Invoice" are set to enabled and "Send Invoice Email Copy Method" is set to Bcc.

The Stripe payments settings are as follows.
[image]

The order notes shows the following order status flow.
[image]

The Stripe payment timeline is as follows
[image]

The Stripe webhooks log shows the following

```
[2022-04-02 14:41:01] webhooks.INFO: Received stripe_payments_webhook_payment_intent_succeeded [] []
[2022-04-02 14:41:01] webhooks.INFO: 200 OK [] []
[2022-04-02 14:41:02] webhooks.INFO: Received stripe_payments_webhook_charge_succeeded [] []
[2022-04-02 14:41:06] webhooks.INFO: 200 OK [] []
```

I've tried toggling between "authorize only" and "authorize and capture" with the same result, also no "invoice" email gets sent, only a "new order confirmation" email.

Tried to disable and enable "async sending" with the same result.

I can't seem to figure out the "New order confirmation" is being sent twice for the same order and the invoice email isn't sent with the successful capture of the payment.

Any help with this would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is now solved with the 3.1.1 update https://github.com/stripe/stripe-magento2-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: It is not solved for us.

Answer (score 1):

Update from Stripe

---

Hello,

This is a quick update to let you know that the problem has been fixed, and will be included in the next release of the module. We anticipate the next release to be publicly available within 1 week.

You can keep an eye for new releases is via one of the following 2 pages:

- The [Magento Marketplace changelog.](https://marketplace.magento.com/stripe-stripe-payments.html#product.info.details.release_notes)
- Stripe’s [changelog on
  Github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-magento2-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

---

[image]

Comment: We just updated to 3.3.1 in our staging env and it did NOT resolve the issue. Magento v2.4.3-p3. We have already emailed your support. By looking at the changelog it is clear Stripe has been battling this issue for some time. A bit more testing before releasing buggy code to their customers would be nice.

Comment: Using Stripe 3.3.4 and this issue is still happening.